# Can questions about sense of technical documentation be asked?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

I'm reading programming documentation (C++ International Standard, for example). But, because English is not my native language, it is possible that I don't understand some chunks of the standard text correctly.

Can I ask English-language oriented questions about programming documentation?

Comment: As long as you link to the documentation and explain which parts you're having trouble understanding (possibly with a quote), and the question doesn't end up being too broad, then I don't see a problem with this...but that's just my personal opinion. **What is your native language?** [area51.se] has a number of [proposed Stack Overflow sites in other languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology?tab=progress).

Comment: Native English speakers don't know what it says, it is written in a language called isoese.  A common topic in [c++], be sure it wasn't asked before.

Comment: Indeed, we have an entire tag for this: [tag:language-lawyer].

Comment: @CodyGray Funny, I didn't know about that tag. Also funny, though perhaps not surprising: it is *all* c++. (Well, c++ and one c.)

Comment: @Cupcake: In the case of standard c++, linking to it is rather hard. Also in the case of standard c++, staying on english SO is probably the better idea, since as Hans said, the language of standard c++ is mostly related to english.

Comment: @neminem: most languages do not have a Standard, just a reference implementation, and thus it would not make sense for them. Well, that and the C and C++ Standards are fairly big and awkward to navigate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All you're saying is **"Can I ask for further clarification or information about a technical topic?"**

The answer is **absolutely yes, click and ask the question.**

Comment: Indeed, and if you have already put the effort into researching it by trying to read an ISO standard, and if you quote from it, that makes for a great question!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, not "technical topics". Questions about the C++ spec are likely to be on-topic, but only if they're actual programming questions (e.g., CS theory doesn't go here).

Comment: @chrylis: The C++ spec is quite formal as language specifications go; e.g. the CS complexity of algorithms is listed. That is non-trivial and can make good questions. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550509/amortized-analysis-of-stdvector-insertion

Comment: @MSalters That's a good question, but it doesn't fit the Stack Overflow on-topic requirements, and if it were asked today, I'd suggest moving it to CS.

Answer (score 14):

It depends how much of a grasp you have on the topic.  If it is really only about the language, you should probably ask on the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange as long as the question can be formed to fit its help center guidelines. Otherwise, you can ask on Stack Overflow if:

- You have thoroughly looked for an answer.
- You mention exactly what is confusing you.
- You explain your current interpretation and any competing or supporting information that you found about the topic.

Comment: It's say if it were only about the language, ell.SE (English Language Learners) would probably be better than English Language & Usage? Though the OP's English seems pretty fluent - just in terms of scope of the two sites.

Comment: @neminem Very true.